# Takes a while to decipher what people say, something wrong with my brain?

Tags: hearing, brain, tumors

Sometimes, when people talk to me, I hear the words immediately but it then takes me longer than expected to decode those words and respond appropriately. This leads to odd pauses and I look a little slow.

*Probably unconnected but...* I also frequently suffer from taking longer than normal to think of a specific word, sometimes I can fill with something similar or someone else fills in for me but still, awkward pauses in conversation.

The thing is, it never used to happen - I was always quite witty and snappy with retorts and could throw together sentences in a blink. I started noticing a couple of years ago and I swear it's getting worse (or maybe I'm noticing more). Oh, I'm 26 by the way. So yeah, I guess it could be something like early-onset dementia but no history in the family! 
Also, I still have a phenomenal memory for numbers/patterns/dates/events etc that I always used to have. That hasn't changed at all. Seems specifically to do with the language centre.

My Granny just recently had an operation to remove a Meningioma, is there any way it could be connected? I don't want to bother the NHS if I'm just imagining things!

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! Here on Health, we cannot reliably answer this question, as it is too personal. There are too many factors and too much information that we don't have access to, so we can't properly diagnose you. Check out [Are personal medical advice questions on topic here?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here) or the disclaimer on the sidebar of this page. I would recommend that you see a doctor instead. Thanks :)

Comment: Try TruBrain - it's like brain vitamins. If I had to guess, it might be mild schizophrenia or schizotypal or something and you could try risperadal, but you'd have to go to your psychiatrist to get that. It often presents in early 20's especially in males.